# Needing help understanding piece of Java code

Tags: java, class, oop

I started learn Java today, following by Head First Java, 2nd Edition, and I have some code, which is confusing to me. I've got experience in Python, but this is new. To be more specific, I don't understand what **boolean canRecord = false;**
actually do.

```
class DVDPlayer {

    boolean canRecord = false;

    void recordDVD() {
        System.out.println("DVD recording");
    }
    void playDVD() {
       System.out.println("DVD playing");
   }    
} 

class DVDPlayerTestDrive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        DVDPlayer d = new DVDPlayer();
        d.canRecord = true;
        d.playDVD();

        if (d.canRecord == true) {
            d.recordDVD();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: delare a boolean variable and set it to false

Comment: If you read Head First Java, there must be mentioned what assignment a value to the variable means. Read the book carefully and don't panic with questions on stack overflow. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your class DVDPlayer you chose to say that a regular DVDPlayer cannot record. So you set it to false.

If you want it to record you either change the variable directly, like you did on the class DVDPlayerTestDrive.

The **boolean canRecord = false** is only meant to show you that it is possible to *reproduce* the behaviour of objects. In this case you have a class that should represent a DVDPlayer and as we know it the majority of DVDPlayers do not record.

Don't focus much on the code during the first approach to Object Oriented Programming (I assume it is your first OOP language too).

Try to understand the concepts and ideas behind it =)

Answer (score 0):

If this example is from a book, then I can not even imagine what the author meant.
My vision of this example is far from ideal, but allows to partially understand the essence of OOP

```
class DVDPlayer {
    private final boolean recordable;

    // by default recordable false
    DVDPlayer() {
        this(false);
    }

    // you can specify recordable
    DVDPlayer(boolean recordable) {
        this.recordable = recordable;
    }

    void playDVD() {
        System.out.println("DVD playing");
    }

    void recordDVD() {
        if (recordable) {
            System.out.println("DVD recording");
        } else {
            System.out.println("non recordable");
        }
    }
}

class DVDPlayerTestDrive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        DVDPlayer d1 = new DVDPlayer(true);
        d1.recordDVD();
        d1.playDVD();

        DVDPlayer d2 = new DVDPlayer();
        d2.recordDVD();
        d2.playDVD();
    }
```

I hope, you get the idea.